# dropdown not working with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to create a menu using ui bootstrap and ng-repeat, however I seem to have an issue with expanding/ collapsing the dropdowns. If I don't use ng-repeat the dropdowns behave like they should, so I must be missing something.

Here is the relevant code:

```
<ul class="navigation">
        <li data-ng-repeat="menuItem in menuItems" data-is-open="item.open" data-ng-class="{ 'dropdown mm-dropdown' : menuItem.subItems }" data-on-toggle="toggle()" role="menu">
            <a href='#' class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <i ng-if="menuItem.icon" class="menu-icon fa {{ menuItem.icon }}"></i>
                <span class="mm-text">{{ menuItem.title }}</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="mmc-dropdown-delay animated fadeInLeft">
                <li>
                    <a tabindex="-1" href="layouts-grid.html"><span class="mm-text">Grid</span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a tabindex="-1" href="layouts-main-menu.html"><i class="menu-icon fa fa-th-list"></i><span class="mm-text">Main menu</span><span class="label label-warning">Updated</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <!--This is working-->
        <li class="dropdown mm-dropdown" data-on-toggle="toggle()">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <i class="menu-icon fa fa-th"></i>
                <span class="mm-text">Layouts</span>
                <span class="label label-warning">Updated</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="mmc-dropdown-delay animated fadeInLeft">
                <li>
                    <a tabindex="-1" href="layouts-grid.html"><span class="mm-text">Grid {{ item.open }}</span></a>
                </li>
                <li data-ng-class="{ 'active': item.active }">
                    <a tabindex="-1" href="layouts-main-menu.html"><i class="menu-icon fa fa-th-list"></i><span class="mm-text">Main menu</span><span class="label label-warning">Updated</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>            
    </ul>
```

All the menu items generated in the ng-repeat section will try to go to the link set by a href instead of expanding, whereas the bottom section is working just fine.

Once I replace the ng-class part with class="dropdown mmc-dropdown" everything seems to work just fine.

What am I missing? I'm just starting off with angular and it seems there is something basic that I am not understanding.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: try `href=""`, because angular by default uses `#` for its routing

Comment: Removing href completely fixed the part where it was trying to change the route. The other issue seems to be that data-ng-class="{ 'dropdown mm-dropdown' : menuItem.subItems }" stops the dropdown from expanding. Replacing it with class="dropdown mmc-dropdown" fixes this issue as well. Any thoughts on why this may be?